# get set property as a bool[] return

Tags: c#, get, set

This is a very basic question.

`void Output(int output);` -> this enables one single output

`bool[] Outputs { get; set; }` -> This enables multiple output. I need the implementation of this. This is an API declared as a interface.

In my class I need to use it.

i studied this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28VS.80%29.aspx... but no where I got reference to get and set returning a bool array.

In the above link, the class is as:

interface IPoint
{
   // Property signatures:
   int x
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
   int y
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}

```
class Point : IPoint
{
   // Fields:
   private int _x;
   private int _y;

   // Constructor:
   public Point(int x, int y)
   {
      _x = x;
      _y = y;
   }

   // Property implementation:
   public int x
   {
      get
      {
         return _x;
      }    
      set
      {
         _x = value;
      }
   }

   public int y
   {
      get
      {
         return _y;
      }
      set
      {
         _y = value;
      }
   }
}
```

what will be the class declaration in my case ??

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool[] Outputs {get; set;}
```

will create a property named "Outputs" returning bool array. This is a shortcut syntax, if you wish to use longer syntax then it would go some thing like

```
private bool[] _outputs;
public bool[] Outputs
{
   get
    {
      return _outputs;
    }
   set
    {
      _outputs = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vinay. 
public interface myInterface
{
     bool[] Outputs { get; set; }
     void Output(int output);
}

class myClass : Form -> here i need to use that myInterface. 
But myClass inherits Form. So what will be the case here ? ?

Comment: You can inherit from one class and multiple interfaces. So just add command and the interface name after form. ( myClass:Form, IMyInterface)

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as the sample on MSDN, but replace "`int`" with "`bool[]`".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample implementation:

```
public class YourAPIImpl: IYourAPI
{
    public bool[] Outputs { get; set; }

    public void Output(int output)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```